# Convert a struct from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

Hi I'm trying to convert a C++ code to a C#, I have searched for a few solutions on the internet, but I can't seem to get any of the results I want. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

The following code is a C++ code.

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef int sint32;
typedef struct BY_BITMAP
{
    sint32 biWidth;      
    sint32 biHeight;     
    sint32 biBitCount;  
    sint32 bfSize;       
    sint32 BytesPerLine; 
    uint8 **ScanLine;    
    uint8 *buffer;       
}BY_BITMAP;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? You need te same in C#? Or do you need something so that C++ and C# codes can interact by?

Comment: We do not know what for what you are using this. Did you read for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs

Comment: Truth be told that looks like C code, not C++.

Comment: If u want the same in C#,what is the challenge?? C# also has structs. If there is a trouble understanding the data types in your C++ code,it is quite simple,you can find their corresponding in C# by a simple search,C# has them all

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a conversion, I think this is the closest of what you want to achieve?

```
public struct BY_BITMAP {
    public int biWidth;
    public int biHeight;
    public int biBitCount;
    public int bfSize;
    public int BytesPerLine;
    public byte[][] ScanLine;
    public byte[] buffer;
}
```